# How to deal with primary key check like situations in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have to load the incremental load to my base table (say table_stg) everyday once. I get the snapshot of data everyday from various sources in xml format. The `id` column is supposed to be unique but since data is coming from different sources, there is a chance of duplicate data.

day1:
`table_stg
id,col2,col3,ts,col4
1,a,b,2016-06-24 01:12:27.000532,c
2,e,f,2016-06-24 01:12:27.000532,k
3,a,c,2016-06-24 01:12:27.000532,l`

day2: (say the xml is parsed and loaded into table_inter as below)

`id,col2,col3,ts,col4
4,a,b,2016-06-25 01:12:27.000417,l
2,e,f,2016-06-25 01:12:27.000417,k
5,w,c,2016-06-25 01:12:27.000417,f
5,w,c,2016-06-25 01:12:27.000417,f`

when i put this data ino table_stg, my final output should be:

`id,col2,col3,ts,col4
1,a,b,2016-06-24 01:12:27.000532,c
2,e,f,2016-06-24 01:12:27.000532,k
3,a,c,2016-06-24 01:12:27.000532,l
4,a,b,2016-06-25 01:12:27.000417,l
5,w,c,2016-06-25 01:12:27.000417,f`

**What could be the best way to handle these kind of situations(without deleting the table_stg(base table) and reloading the whole data)**

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073388/avoiding-data-duplication-when-loading-data-from-multiple-servers and also somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004374/refresh-one-hive-table-from-another-hive-table/32007278#32007278

Comment: Plus some clean-up on the input since it may have some duplicates to begin with -- `SELECT id, a, b, c FROM (SELECT id, a, b, c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY` <your rule> `) AS zz FROM src) xx WHERE zz=1 AND NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709411 You can apply the same technique (full join). And of course clean-up duplicates as   @Samson Scharfrichter has already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does allow duplicates on primary and unique keys.You should have an upstream job doing the data cleaning before loading it into the Hive table.
You can write a python script for that if data is less or use spark if data size is huge.

spark provides dropDuplicates() method to achieve this.